# how to concatenate (part of) variable to String in XSLT

Tags: string, variables, xslt, string-concatenation

I would like to see the first couple of characters of the variable 'vari' to be concatenated to String abc=' here:

```
href="{concat('abc=', substring-before('vari', '='))}"
```

Here is the whole snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="report:subelement">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <message>
              <xsl:variable name="vari"  select="."></xsl:variable>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </message>
        </td>
        <td>
           <button type="button"  onclick="window.location.href=this.getAttribute('href')"  href="{concat('abc=', substring-before('vari', '='))}" >Kill thread</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

that is probably a trivial question but I am just learning xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, but:
To access the value of a variable you have to use an dollar  (`$`) as prefix. Do not put variable name in apostrophe.
Therefore try:

```
href="{concat('abc=', substring-before($vari, '='))}
```

Than this  will throw an error because your variable declaration is not in the same context as the usage. 
The variable declaration has to be in the same element or in an ancestor. Put the declaration at the top of the subelement template or the in the `<tr` element.

Updated working template:

```
<xsl:template match=""report:subelement">
    <xsl:variable name="vari"  select="."></xsl:variable>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <message>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </message>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button"  onclick="window.location.href=this.getAttribute('href')" 
                    href="{concat('abc=', substring-before($vari, '='))}" >Kill thread</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks, but if I declare a variable how can later assign a value to it?

Comment: You can't. The value of an variable is not changeable. Perhaps you should updated your question with an more complete example.

Comment: Then I don't understand. If I cant assign a value, then what can I read form it later?